# Db_Query Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

Tags: routes

I am simply trying to return the rows from a table in my db but i keep getting this error thrown back at me no matter what I do "Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\xampp\htdocs\d7\includes\form.inc on line 1009". Am I missing a argument or something?

This is my function

Hook menu

```
function auto_form_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['admin/config/auto_form'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Module',
    'description' => 'description',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('auto_form_records'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'file' => 'auto_form.admin.inc'
);

$items['admin/config/auto_form/manage'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Module',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'description' => 'description',
    'weight' => -10,
);
return $items;
}
```

'auto_form.admin.inc'

```
function auto_form_records() {
  $header = array('First Name', 'Last Name');

  $dbresult = db_query("SELECT first, last FROM {auto}");

    $rows = array();
    foreach ($dbresult as $dbrow) {
        $rows[] = array(
        $dbrow->first,
        $dbrow->last
      );
    }
    return $output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
}
```

Updated Code:

Any help is appreciated seeing how I am completely lost on figuring this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what it was, it was hook_menu in my module. It was looking for a form when there was no form in place by using drupal_get_form as a page callback. If i change the page callback to the function being used in the file the error goes away and the results come back. Please see the example below...

Hook menu

```
function auto_form_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['admin/config/auto_form'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Module',
    'description' => 'description',
    'page callback' => 'auto_form_records',
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'file' => 'auto_form.admin.inc'
);

$items['admin/config/auto_form/manage'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Module',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'description' => 'description',
    'weight' => -10,
);
return $items;
}
```

Function in my inc file

```
function auto_form_records() {
  $header = array('First Name', 'Last Name');

  $dbresult = db_query("SELECT first, last FROM {auto}");

    foreach ($dbresult as $dbrow) {
        $rows[] = array(
        $dbrow->first,
        $dbrow->last
      );
    }
    return $output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly which one is causing the error but there are a couple of things:

- You're trying to loop over a variable called `$dbresult` which you haven't declared; you probably meant

  ```
  $dbresult = db_query("SELECT first, last FROM {autoform}");

  $results = '';
  foreach ($dbresult as $dbrow) {
  ```
- It looks like you're using Drupal 7, and the call you're making to `theme_table` contains arguments in the style of the Drupal 6 call. Variables are all named in Drupal 7 so you need to invoke the function like this:

  ```
  $output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $data));
  ```
- `theme_table()` takes an array of rows, and each of those arrays will have the data for a number of columns, one for each that you've defined in your header. At the moment you're concatenating a single string and creating a single row containing one cell, with that single string in it.

  I think something like this is more what you're after:

  ```
  $rows = array();
  foreach ($dbresult as $dbrow) {
    $rows[] = array(
      $dbrow->first,
      $dbrow->last
    );
  }

  $output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
  ```

Also if you want a nice little shortcut leveraging some of the db API you could use this reduced code:

```
$header = array('first' => 'First Name', 'last' => 'Last Name');
$rows = db_query("SELECT first, last FROM {autoform}")->fetchAllAssoc();
$output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
```

That last snippet will become less useful the more you need to customise the individual rows/cells of the table.

Comment: I apologized for the example I got mixed up with some of the other coding that I pasted. I tried your 1st example and some how I am still getting the same error, could it possibly something in my hook_menu?

Comment: Did you fix the other problems up as well?

Comment: Yes, updated code to show you the current selected code im using