# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in form.inc

Tags: 7, routes

I'm getting the following error message:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/public_html/domain.com/includes/form.inc on line 1079

It seems to be because the following code for an admin menu.

```
function MY_MODULE_admin_menu() {
  $menu_items = db_query("SELECT * FROM my_module")->fetchAll();
  $header = array('Template ID', 'Name', 'Type', 'Template');
  $rows = array();
  if (!empty($menu_items)) {
    foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
      $rows[] = array($menu_item->tid, $menu_item->name, $menu_item->type, $menu_item->template);
    }
  }
  return theme_table(array(
    "header" => $header,
    "rows" => $rows,
    "attributes" => array(),
    "sticky" => true,
    "caption" => "",
    "colgroups" => array(),
    "empty" => t("Table has no rows"),
      )
  );
}
```

What's causing this? As far as I can tell, this is how it is supposed to look for Drupal 7.

Comment: As side note, you should never call a theme function directly, as in `theme_table()`; you should call `theme()` or simply return a render array.

Comment: I tried theme() and got another error, IIRC, so I switched to theme_table(). I also figured out this error and will be posting a solution.

Comment: Furthermore, form.inc doesn't contain `theme_table()`, so the code causing the error is not the one you are showing.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of this question:

[Db_Query Fatal error: Unsupported operand types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45807/db-query-fatal-error-unsupported-operand-types)

It turns out that I was setting my page callback to a drupal_get_form with no form present.

I changed my hook_menu to:

```
function MY_MODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/structure/module'] = array(
    'title' => 'description of module',
    'description' => 'Configure settings for module',
    'page callback' => 'MY_MODULE_admin_menu',
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

And it worked fine.